# In Python how do you split a list into evenly sized chunks starting with the last element from the previous chunk?

Tags: python, list

What would be the most pythonic way to convert  a list like:

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

into chunks of `n` elements that always start with the last element of the previous chunk. 
The last element of the last chunk should be identical to the first element of the first chunk to make the data structure circular.
Like:

```
[
[0,1,2,3],
[3,4,5,6],
[6,7,8,0],
]
```

under the assumption that `len(mylist) % (n-1) == 0` . So that it always works nicely.

Comment: So the length of your chunks is your defining variable, or the number of chunks?

Comment: @sr2222 could be either, for my problem the number of chunks would actually be the better defining variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the straightforward solution?

```
splitlists = [mylist[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n-1)]
splitlists[-1].append(splitlists[0][0])
```

Comment: you can use `[(lis+[lis[0]])[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(lis), n-1)]`, to skip the second step

Answer (score 0):

A much less straightforward solution involving numpy (for the sake of overkill):

```
from numpy import arange, roll, column_stack

n = 4    
values = arange(10, 26)  
# values -> [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25]

idx = arange(0, values.size, n)   # [ 0  4  8 12]
idx = roll(idx, -1)               # [ 4  8 12  0] 

col = values[idx]                 # [14 18 22 10]

values = column_stack( (values.reshape(n, -1), col) )

[[10 11 12 13 14]
 [14 15 16 17 18]
 [18 19 20 21 22]
 [22 23 24 25 10]]
```

Comment: is there any benefit in this ?

Comment: It depends. If you use the default array dtype (int64) the pure python solution performs as well as the numpy one. As you start decreasing the integer size, you begin to see significant improvements. See: https://gist.github.com/3655860